# Queue Python User Input

Tags: python, append, user-input

I'm new in Python Language, our professor gave us activity about creating a queue list but I'm very confuse how to do it. The task is to display the movies and snacks that the user entered. Every time it press S the snacks will be remove. I hope someone could explain why this happens and what should I add. Thank you very much.

```
Movies = [];
movie = str (input ("Enter a movie 1 of 3: "));
Movies.append(movie)
movie = str (input ("Enter a movie 2 of 3: "));
Movies.append(movie)
movie = str (input ("Enter a movie 3 of 3: "));
Movies.append(movie)

Snack = [];
snack = str (input ("Enter snack 1 of 3: "));
Snack.append(snack)
snack = str (input ("Enter snack 2 of 3: "));
Snack.append(snack)
snack = str (input ("Enter snack 3 of 3: "));
Snack.append(snack)

print("Movies to watch are ", Movies);

print("Snacks available are ", snack);

print("Press S each time you finish a snack.");
eat = input();
if str.lower(eat)== "s":
 print (snack.pop());
 print (snack);
```

```
Output: 

Enter a movie 1 of 3: Avengers 
Enter a movie 2 of 3: Forrest Gump
Enter a movie 3 of 3: Lucy
Enter snack 1 of 3: Milktea
Enter snack 2 of 3: Pizza
Enter snack 3 of 3: Fries
Movies to watch are  ['Avengers', 'Forrest Gump', 'Lucy']
Snacks available are  fries #this is my problem
Press S each time you finish a snack.
S
```

Comment: There is a typo in code. print("Snacks available are ", snack) should be print("Snacks available are ", Snack);

Comment: This kind of thing is why you don't just name one variable the same thing as another but capitalized differently.

Comment: Thanks, I should change the variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python variables are case-sensitive, in the last part you are overlapping `snack` and `Snack` so try:

```
print("Movies to watch are ", Movies);

print("Snacks available are ", Snack);

print("Press S each time you finish a snack.");
eat = input();
if str.lower(eat)== "s":
 print (Snack.pop());
 print (Snack);
```